# 301 Redirect does not display images from xml file

Tags: xml, .htaccess, flash, redirect

I created an .htaccess file so I could redirect a popular, but deprecated audio player that has a swf that reads an XML that tells it what image to display in the bg of the player. The following is the only entry in the file.

```
redirect 301 /popup-player.php http://player.domain.com/popup-player2.php/
```

The redirect works as far as redirecting the user to the new URL, but the bg image is not displayed in the swf player.

The XML is another directory and the image in another.

Do I have to somehow include the resources in the .htaccess file also and how?

Comment: I assume you have changed the paths to the images in the XML as well ? :) Is the flash player getting the XML file first? Do you have a crossdomain.xml on your new server?

Comment: All I am doing is deprecating an old php file by redirecting to a whole new php. So when people type in www.domain.com/popup-player.php it redirects them to the new file www.domain.com/popup-player2.php

Comment: @Jason you might need to show a link of problem in action. Easier to check the problem that way.